# Test with consecutive calls to MockWebServer

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing, mockwebserver

I am writing test for an Activity which makes several consecutive calls to server.
My MockWebServer mixes sequence of responses.e.g. When I make two consecutive requests request1 and request2 it sometimes returns request2's Json in response to request1 and request1's Json in response to request2.
How can I specify which response MockWebServer has to return to specified request?

```java
server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(readFromFile("response1 path"));

server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(readFromFile("response2 path"));
```

In documentation it is said "Enqueue scripts response to be returned to a request made in sequence. The first request is served by the first enqueued response; the second request by the second enqueued response; and so on."

This sequence doesn't work in case of parallel requests.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To handle the sequence  of responses I have written a dispatcher for my MockServer instance.
It receives a request, checks it's URL's endpoint and returns corresponding response

```java
Dispatcher mDispatcher = new Dispatcher() {
    @Override
    public MockResponse dispatch(RecordedRequest request) {
         if (request.getPath().contains("/request1")) {
             return new MockResponse().setBody("reponse1");
         }
         if (request.getPath().contains("/request2")) {
             return new MockResponse().setBody("reponse2");
         }
         return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(404);
       }
     }
 mMockServer.setDispatcher(mDispatcher);
```

Comment: Can you assign a different dispatcher for each test?

Comment: Each server has one dispatcher.So if you want to have many dispatchers you have to create many servers,which is not optimal.So you shall find a way to handle many responses in one dispatcher.

Comment: While it will most likely be possible to find a way to handle all tests in one dispatcher another approach could be to instantiate and close the mockwebserver in BeforeEach instead of BeforeAll. So you have one server per test and can setDispatcher individually.