# How to make sure an asynchronous test doesn't interfere with another?

Tags: kotlin, junit, concurrency, awaitility

I would like to unit test the behavior of my function which uses an asynchronous call to external API (using WebClient, but I doubt it is relevant).
A simplified version of the flow of the function would be this

```
fun foo() {
  if (conditionIsMet) {
    thread(start = true) {
      externalApi.post()
    }
  } else {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

In my test file, I therefore have 2 tests, which test both if branches.

In the test where condition is met, I have mocked the external API call using MockWebServer, then use *Awaitility* to wait for the call to end

```
await().untilAsserted {
  verify { externalApi.post() }
}
```

In the other test, I check that this call is not made :
`verify (exactly = 0) { externalApi.post() }`

When I run both tests separately, they both work without a hitch. The problems arise when I run them at the same time (I run all tests of the file, the same way that `maven test` would do). Then, my second test fails, probably because it sees the call made in the other test.

I am not familiar with execution contexts in threads, so I have a shallow understanding of what is happening

**What I have tried** :

- Putting a lock on my test function, locking it on @BeforeEach and unlocking it on @AfterEach so that they would run sequentially
- replacing thread by coroutine in my code
- Naïvely put Thread.sleep() in my tests to force it to wait

None of this has worked, and I'm quite at a loss. Can anyone help ?

Comment: This sounds like a related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458960/test-with-consecutive-calls-to-mockwebserver

Comment: I believe our issues differ, as I have a single call to mockwebserver over both tests (the second test doesn't call the api, but however 'sees' it in the assertion anyway due to concurrency interaction)